# Low performance of HTTP request using Haskell wreq

Tags: performance, haskell, memory-management, http

The program makes HTTP requests (checks video stream status) and calls an external program.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
import Control.Lens ((&), (.~), (^.))
import Network.HTTP.Client (HttpException(..))
import Network.Wreq
import Data.Text (Text, null)
import Data.Aeson.Lens (key, _String)
import Control.Exception as E
import System.Process (callCommand)

streamCheckList :: [(String, String)]
streamCheckList = [ ("tempsnip2", "python bot_n.py 2")
                  , ("tempsnip3", "python bot.py 3"  )
                  , ("tempsnip4", "python bot.py 4"  )
                  ]

tokenAndSignatureBaseUrl :: String -> String
tokenAndSignatureBaseUrl ch = concat [ "https://api.twitch.tv/api/channels/"
                                     , ch, "/access_token" ]

tokenAndSignature :: String -> IO (Response B.ByteString)
tokenAndSignature ch = get $ tokenAndSignatureBaseUrl ch

hlsPlaylistBaseUrl :: String -> String
hlsPlaylistBaseUrl ch = concat [ "http://usher.twitch.tv/api/channel/hls/"
                               , ch, ".m3u8" ]

hlsPlaylist :: (String, Text, Text) -> IO (Response B.ByteString)
hlsPlaylist (ch, token, sig) = let opts = defaults & param "token" .~ [token]
                                                   & param "sig"   .~ [sig]
                               in getWith opts $ hlsPlaylistBaseUrl ch

restartIfNeeded :: (String, String) -> IO ()
restartIfNeeded (ch, cmd) = do streamAccessible <- isStreamAccessible ch
                               if streamAccessible
                               then print $ ch ++ " stream is accessible"
                               else do print $ "restarting " ++ ch
                                       restart cmd

restart :: String -> IO ()
restart existingProcessCmd = (callCommand $ concat [ "pkill --full \""
                                                   , existingProcessCmd
                                                   , "\""
                                                   ]) `E.catch` handler
                               where
                                handler :: E.IOException -> IO ()
                                handler e = print e

-- in fact we try to fetch an hls m3u playlist of stream
isStreamAccessible :: String -> IO Bool
isStreamAccessible ch = do
    E.try (tokenAndSignature ch) >>= tsHandler
      where
        tsHandler :: Either HttpException (Response B.ByteString) -> IO Bool
        tsHandler (Left _) = return False
        tsHandler (Right rToSig)
          = let token = rToSig ^. responseBody . key "token" . _String
                sig = rToSig ^. responseBody . key "sig" . _String
            in if Data.Text.null token || Data.Text.null sig
               then return False
               else E.try (hlsPlaylist (ch, token, sig)) >>= pHandler
        pHandler :: Either HttpException (Response B.ByteString) -> IO Bool
        pHandler (Left _) = return False
        pHandler (Right _) = return True

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ restartIfNeeded streamCheckList
```

The problem is that the program uses too much CPU. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123475/profiling-builds-with-stack), I've built with:

```
stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-Wall -fprof-auto -rtsopts"
```

`tokenAndSignature` takes 26.7% of CPU time with 43.2% allocs. Also it happens so that it's the function which result is used later by lens to decode JSON from. Inner functions of `tokenAndSignature` contain many `decodeLenientWithTable` functions (from `Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal` module) with 550000 entries on average which looks awkward to me.

Yes, I use String type here. But it's only because [wreq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html)'s library `get` function requires `String` as its argument.

`stack exec -- test +RTS -sstderr` shows that almost 1/3 of time is spent on GC:

```
MUT     time    1.604s  (  5.535s elapsed)
GC      time    0.514s  (  0.505s elapsed)
...
Productivity  76.9% of total user, 28.2% of total elapsed
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: I'm not really sure that this is a code review question.  Since you already know something is wrong shouldn't you be asking in one of the programming questions sections.

Comment: What kind of response (typical length and JSON structure) is returned by `hlsPlaylist`?

Comment: `B.length` for `responseBody` of `Response` returned by `hlsPlaylist` returns 713. But it's content type is not JSON: ("Content-Type","application/vnd.apple.mpegurl").
But `tokenAndSignature` returns `Response` with ("Content-Type","application/json; charset=utf-8"). And it's `responseBody` length is 333.

Comment: `tokenAndSignature` JSON response example:
{
"token":"{\"user_id\":null,\"channel\":\"snipealot2\",\"expires\":1386615270,\"chansub\":{\"view_until\":1924905600,\"restricted_bitrates\":[]},\"private\":{\"allowed_to_view\":true},\"privileged\":false}",
"sig":"ca666ec55c72b12ed42bda9bf88b9926ef1f5bfb",
"mobile_restricted":false
}

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. `tokenAndSignature` actually makes the network request (`get`), so it makes sense to me that it would allocate a bunch of memory and utilize the CPU. Check this SO answer about [reducing Haskell binary size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6115703/6513157). "High CPU usage in 'htop'" is too non-specific to address. Edit the actual profiling result into your question, right now we've got nothing concrete to pick over.

Comment: The question title was edited. Originally it was "Unexpectedly high CPU usage for...". `hlsPlaylist` also makes a network request (`getWith`) as well as `tokenAndSignature`, but it's `responseBody` is not analyzed (only status code). What's the right way to measure CPU usage of this program?

Comment: @Michael If the problem is efficiency, the question is on topic.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a *really* old question but, have you tried using a `Session` instance when calling `wreq`'s `getWith`? Using the `getWith` version included in `Network.Wreq` creates a separate session for each request, hindering resource sharing and heavily increasing memory usage. It can also cause memory fragmentation, which translates into an increasingly larger resident size reported by the OS.

See the [API reference](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.3.3/docs/Network-Wreq-Session.html).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Someday, I will try this code snippet again.